# diplaying both Graphical and Textual XML edit view in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

is it possible in eclipse to display both Graphical Layout view next to a Textual XML Editor for the same XML Layout file?

the reason is that i want to see the results in the graphical layout as soon as i save changes to the XML Editor, without the need to change tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open any file in Eclipse in multiple editors and display them side-by-side. All editors referencing the same file will share the same editing buffer, so the changes in one should be reflected in the other. Just right click on the file and use the "Open With" menu item to open the editors you need. Then drag the opened editors around your workbench so that they are displayed side-by-side.